# How was the problem of dive bomber scope fogging resolved during WW2?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, aviation-history, wwii

During the first half of 1942, US Navy SBD bombers had problems with their bomb aiming scopes fogging over, which reduced the accuracy of their bombing during several early war operations. Was this resolved by better scopes, improvements to the existing scopes or replacing them with reflector sights?

Comment: Astronomers use heaters to keep their lenses from fogging up. Would not be surprised if this was also the solution.

Comment: This [answer on quora to a similar question](https://www.quora.com/During-the-early-part-of-the-Pacific-War-how-did-the-gun-bombsight-for-the-SBD-Dauntless-able-to-fog-up) suggests it was fixed in the SBD-5 by using a reflector based sight instead..

Comment: @JuanJimenez A good telescope would not have a heater because the heater would cause turbulence that would ruin the image.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist You are mistaken. It's called a dew heater and they are very commonly used. https://optcorp.com/collections/dew-heaters

Comment: @JuanJimenez "Good" was a key word there.  Those are for small hobbyist telescopes.  Humidity is low at good locations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teide_Observatory https://elt.eso.org/about/location/ https://www.maunakeaobservatories.org/maunakea-is-unique/

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Which explains why they are not needed in those larger telescopes. "Hobbyist" is an irrelevant term in this discussion. No one is going to spend a lot of money on a large telescope and then place it in a high humidity location, so they don't need them. That's all it is. The fact is that they do not "ruin" any image, otherwise no one would use them.

Comment: @JuanJimenez "No one is going to spend a lot of money on a large telescope and then place it in a high humidity location, so they don't need them."  Astronomers working on site for a nice telescope constantly complain about how cold it is; they do want heaters for the astronomers, but do not use them because it would, in fact, ruin the image.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist No they don't ruin the image, and I am done with this stupid conversation. Moderator, please move it into a discussion area.

Comment: And it's pretty close to off topic, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fogging problems were solved by switching from a telescopic to a reflective gun sight.

From [The Dauntless Dive Bomber of World War Two](https://books.google.com/books?id=ilT5AgAAQBAJ) by [Barrett Tillman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_Tillman), chapter 1:

> The SBD-1 through the -4 were equipped with a three-power telescopic
> sight, a holdover from the open-cockpit aircraft of the thirties. The
> pilot looked through the tube, lining up the crosshairs on the target
> while keeping a ball much like that of a turn-and-bank indicator
> centered in its groove. The centered ball told him the aircraft was
> level in the dive, otherwise the bomb would go off on a tangent when
> released. The drawback to the telescopic sight was its tendency to fog
> over in a dive from high altitude because of a sudden change of
> temperature, and the resulting condensation clouded the lens. The
> windscreen was also prone to fogging, and pilots said the tubular
> sight was inadequate for aerial gunnery since it severely limited the
> field of vision.
>
> The answer was a reflector gunsight nearly identical to those used in fighter aircraft.
>
> Beginning with the SBD-5, Mark VIII reflecting gunsights were installed, as were heaters for the windscreens. These measures eliminated the problem and were instrumental in improving bombing accuracy. But they were not available until 1943.
> ”

An image of the Mk. VIII reflecting sight mentioned, [provided by the US Air Force Museum](https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Upcoming/Photos/igphoto/2000467864/):

[image]

Comment: There is something wrong here because telescopes can be reflectors.  Both mirrors and lenses can fog.  Modern high quality mirrors are made of the same glass as high quality lenses, but with a thin metal coating.  The cause of the fogging is the heat capacity of the glass.